# Consumir Api en Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

Intento consumir un api que devuelve un string que está en base64 y necesito tenerlo en una variable para convertirla a una imagen. He googleado y tratado de varias maneras pero siempre me da errores. La api a consumir es: "http://smxmex.dyndns.org/imagenes/api/values"
Estos son los intentos que llevo:

Aquí intentando usar Jquery con Ajax

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://smxmex.dyndns.org/imagenes/api/values',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.error("No es posible completar la operación");
        }
    });

});
```

Esta forma la encontré en internet con HTTP

```
const url = 'http://smxmex.dyndns.org/imagenes/api/values'
 const http = new XMLHttpRequest()
 
 http.open("GET", url)
 http.onreadystatechange = function(){
 
     if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
         var resultado = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
         console.log(resultado.name)
     }
 }
 http.send()
```

Aqui usando AXIOS

import axios from 'axios';

```
 export default {
     // ...
 }
 
 axios.get('http://smxmex.dyndns.org/imagenes/api/values')
 .then(response => {
     console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(e => {
     console.log('e:', e)
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque la API no te esta retornando un contenido valido, tu mismo puedes corroborarlo visitando la URL que has colocado, tienes básicamente 2 opciones

1. corregir la API para que retorne un valor valido.
2. utilizar expresiones regulares para extraer el contenido deseado antes de utilizarlo.

Edito:

En javascript puedes usar expresiones regulares dentro de la funcion split
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split

```
var nombres = "Harry Trump ;Fred Barney; Helen Rigby ; Bill Abel ;Chris Hand ";
document.write(nombres + "<br>" + "<br>");
var expresionRegular = /\s*;\s*/;
var listaNombres = nombres.split(expresionRegular);
document.write(listaNombres);
```

del lado de servidor también podrías hacerlo, aunque dependerá del lenguaje que uses, en PHP tienes

```
preg_match('/[a-b]/', $string, $arrayValores)
```

Comment: Ah entiendo. La API no podría arreglarla. Te molestaría indicarme como podría extraer el contenido usando las expresiones regulares?

Comment: Edite mi respuesta anterior con un ejemplo de como podrías usar expresiones regulares